# output array is NULL

Tags: arrays, ajax, codeigniter

i am trying to send javascript array to CI controller but the array is NULL i tried strigify too but still the output array is null
help me with this please.

this is script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(){
            var TableData = new Array();
            $('#sampleTbl tr').each(function(row, tr){
                TableData[row]={
                    "Day" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    "A" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    "B" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    "C" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
                }
            }); 
            TableData.shift(); 
            var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
            console.log(TableData);
            console.log(fullname);
            var arr = JSON.strigify(TableData);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('site/ajax');?>',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {arr: arr},
                success: function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the form

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>site/ajax" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="button">
    <table id="sampleTbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>coloum A</th>
            <th>coloum B</th>
            <th>coloum C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>sunday a</td>
            <td>sunday b</td>
            <td>sunday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>monday a</td>
            <td>monday b</td>
            <td>monday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>tuesday a</td>
            <td>tuesday b</td>
            <td>tuesday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>wednesday a</td>
            <td>wednesday b</td>
            <td>wednesday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>tdursday</td>
            <td>tdursday a</td>
            <td>tdursday b</td>
            <td>tdursday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>friday a</td>
            <td>friday b</td>
            <td>friday c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td>saturday a</td>
            <td>saturday b</td>
            <td>saturday c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

this is the controller part

```
public function ajax(){

    $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
    $arr = $this->input->post('arr');
    $array = json_decode($arr);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $fullname;
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($array);
    // var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: `data: {arr: arr}` where did you define arr ?

Comment: i changed the code now

Comment: @cks if my answer helps you to achieve your goal then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "strigify" method on JSON object.
Use this line instead: `var arr = JSON.stringify(TableData);`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending `key/value` pairs in your data. only a value which is the stringified array. With no key assigned, `$_POST` will be empty

There is really no need to `stringifiy` the array either. jQuery will convert to form encoded array internally.

Try without using it.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: your_url,
    data : {arr: arr},
    dataType: "json"
})......
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function ajax(){
$arr = $this->input->post('arr');
// So on ...    
}
```